# Best ways to convert non-json string to json?

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization

I was trying to come up with good solution to convert string to json format but I don't know if it is good enough.

`String str = "[(Name:"What We "Need" In Life"Author:"David D."FileSize:2.17)(Name:"The House Of Owls"Author:"Carlos")(Name:"A Poor Wise Man"Author:"Steve Bark"FileSize:1.31)]";`

I think maybe I will use str.replace from ( to { and insert comma between the }{ but how can I find the index to insert? and what about the "" for Name,Author,FileSize? After converting to readable json string then I can serialize to json (by gson/jackson).

Comment: first of all, this is not a valid json format. except ( you should use {, you forgot the commas, and inner quotation marks should differ from the surrounding ones. you also forgot commas between the attributes. if you have a valid json string, and are using gson/jackson correctly (e.g. with annotations for serialization values if necessary) you do not need to fiddle around with string methods and can directly use mapping methods from those libraries..

Comment: That string looks hard to parse. The nested doublequotes and no separator to break on in `(Name:"What We "Need" In Life"Author:"David D."FileSize:2.17)`. Any chance you can get different raw data? Are you in control of that string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the string you receive does not follow a known standard (Json, Xml...) but it still has a defined structure, then you need to parse the string into the structure that suits you most.

In your example, the string seems to have the structure:

- A list of books wrapped into `[...]`
- Each book is wrapped into `(...)`
- Inside each book there is a `Name`, an `Author` and sometimes a `FileSize`.

So basically your POJO is the following:

```
public class Book {
    private final String name;
    private final String author;
    private final double fileSize;

    public Book(String name, String author, double fileSize) {
        this.name = name;
        this.author = author;
        this.fileSize = fileSize;
    }
}
```

What you need to do is to parse your `String` into a `List<Book>`. At that point, you can use whatever library (Jackson if you want Json, Jaxb if you want Xml etc.) to annotate your POJOs and let the libraries serialize/deserialize for you.

In order to parse your `String`, the following approach should work:

```
    //First, extract all the books (text between two parentheses):
    Pattern bookPattern = Pattern.compile("\\(([^()]*)\\)");
    Matcher bookMatcher = bookPattern.matcher(str);
    List<String> rawBooks = new ArrayList<>();
    while (bookMatcher.find()) {
        rawBooks.add(bookMatcher.group(1));
    }

    //Then for each book extracted separate the name (string), author (string) and fileSize (number):
    List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
    rawBooks.forEach(rb -> {
        String name = rb.split("Name:")[1].split("Author")[0];
        boolean hasFileSize = rb.contains("FileSize");
        String author;
        double fileSize;
        if (hasFileSize) {
            author = rb.split("Author:")[1].split("FileSize")[0];
            fileSize = Double.parseDouble(rb.split("FileSize:")[1]);
        } else {
            author = rb.split("Author:")[1];
            fileSize = 0;
        }
        books.add(new Book(name, author, fileSize));
    });
```

Now serialize your `books` variable as you want using the right library.

Comment: Thank you for the solution! this help me very much to start somewhere... but do you have any suggestion about this string? (this is more complicated version): 

String str = "[(Name:"What We "Need" In Life"Author:"David D."FileSize:2.17(FileName:"whatweneed_book"FileType:"Word"))(Name:"The House Of Owls"Author:"Carlos"FileSize:"4.72")(Name:"House and Garden"Author:"Nadia F.")(Name:"A Poor Wise Man"Author:"Steve Bark"FileSize:"1.31"(FileName:12345FileType:"PDF"))]";

Every values can be either string, integer or double, and there can be unlimited nested object.

Comment: @newoobie it doesn't seem that this second string follows any structure. You can't really discover data which are unstructured, or you can try but that's going to be hard though. I suggest you start with what I proposed above, create some unit tests with different cases, and work on the source code to make it comply with all the unit tests.

Comment: I tried with your suggestion above and it was gold :) Thank you! I do have more questions about regex, I've got another task to map/serialize this pattern of object. Given ((a(b))(c(d)(e))) with this kind of string, can I use some regex to split object "a" and "b" and then do the same for the inner object (recursion)? I could get out only [a(b),c(d),(e)]

Comment: @newoobie I think this is another question, so I suggest you mark this answer as accepted to close the thread, and post a new question with the code you get so far so that me or someone else can help further (it's hard to write code in the comments :)

Comment: Okay, I will post a new thread. Thank you for helping and answering my question :)